# Thymeleaf - local file as a picture

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a sample image on my computer

```
C:\Users\Jonatan\avatar\Koala.jpg
```

I want to add it to an HTML page as an image. I'm using Thymeleaf so I want to do it this way

```
<img id="avatar" th:src="@{session.user.getUrlAvatar()}"
                                 class="avatar img-circle img-thumbnail" alt="avatar">
```

In this user session I have my own total address, same as above. After compiling unfortunately throws the error

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "@{session.user.getUrlAvatar()}"
```

I tried to register this folder

```
registry
            .addResourceHandler("/avatar/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:///" + System.getProperty("user.home").replace("\\", "/"));
```

But still does not work.

Does anyone know how to do this? I just want to use a local file from drive C.

Answer (score 0):

The expression for the link has to be evaluated, so you need to use `${...}`:

`<img id="avatar" th:src="@{${session.user.getUrlAvatar()}}" class="avatar img-circle img-thumbnail" alt="avatar">`